# JSON filtering attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

What is the best way to filter JSON nested keys and delete them? For example:

```
{ "id"    : "1",
  "key1"  : "val1",
  "key2"  : "val2",
  "name"  : "someone",
  "age"   : 39,
  "data"  : [
    { "id"    : "1234",
      "key1"  : "val1",
      "key2"  : "val2",
      "name"  : "someone",
      "age"   : 39
    },
    { "id"    : "1234",
      "key1"  : "val1",
      "key2"  : "val2",
      "name"  : "someone",
      "age"   : 39
    }
  ]
}
```

To get the following JSON by deleting all `key1` and `key2` items recursively:

```
{ "id"    : "1",
  "name"  : "someone",
  "age"   : 39,
  "data"  : [
    { "id"    : "1234",
      "name"  : "someone",
      "age"   : 39
    },
    { "id"    : "1234",
      "name"  : "someone",
      "age"   : 39
    }
  ] 
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check your curly braces, you have syntax errors in there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
function deleteRecursive(data, key) {
    for(var property in data) {
        if(data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            if(property == key) {
                delete data[key];
            }

            else {
                if(typeof data[property] === "object") {
                    deleteRecursive(data[property], key);
                }
            }
        }         
    }
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2z3mn/)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is the JSON for an object called, say, `people`, something like this should work:

```
function objWithoutPropsIDontLike(obj, propsIDontLike) {
  // check to make sure the given parameter is an object
  if(typeof obj == "object" && obj !== null) { // typeof null gives "object" ಠ_ಠ
    // for every property name... (see note on Object.keys() and
    // Array.forEach() below)
    obj.keys().forEach(function(prop) {
      // Test if the property name is one of the ones you don't like
      // (Array.indexOf() returns -1 if the item isn't found in the array).
      if(propsIDontLike.indexOf(prop) >= 0) {
        // if it is, nuke it
        delete obj[prop];
      } else if(obj[prop]) {
        // if it isn't, recursively filter it
        obj[prop] = filterPropsIDontLike(obj[prop], propsIDontLike);
      }
    });
  }

  // There is no else { ... }; if the thing given for "obj" isn't an object
  // just return it as-is.
  return obj;
}

var propsIDontLike  = [ 'key1', 'key2' ];

people = objWithoutPropsIDontLike(people, propsIDontLike);
```

#### Note:

`Object.keys()` and `Array.forEach()` aren't available in Internet Explorer < 9. Happily MDC provides working polyfills for both: [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains your answer: recursively!

Your base cases are the "primitive" JSON types: strings and numbers.  These remain unchanged.  For arrays, you apply the operation to each element of the array, returning a new array.

The interesting case is objects.  Here, for each key-value pair, you apply the operation to each value (but ignore those whose key is one you would like to "delete") and write them into a new object.

As an (off the cuff) example, using jQuery:

```
var removeKey(object, key){
    if(typeof(object)==='number' || typeof(object)==='string'){
        return object;
    }
    else if(typeof(object)==='object'){
        var newObject = {};
        $.each(object, function(k, value) { 
            if(k!==key){
                newObject[k] = removeKey(value, key);
            }
        });
        return newObject;
    }
    else {
        // Oh dear, that wasn't really JSON!
    }
};
```

If you want to remove more than one key, adjust the second parameter and condition in the recursive case as you see fit.

**NOTE** This is a non-destructive, which may or may not be what you need; the other answer (by Vivin Paliath) has a destructive version.